# Websocket works in incognito Chrome but not in regular Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, websocket

I wrote an app that uses websocket and I am running into a weird problem.

If I run my app in Chrome and try to reconnect, it cannot reconnect to the websocket.

However if I use incognito Chrome, it works every single time.

Is there a subtle difference between the websocket in Chrome vs incognito Chrome? Some sort of cache control maybe?

EDIT: I'm running Chrome 13. Sorry I can't provide any sample code as it reveals my app but the gist of the issue is that incognito Chrome can establish a connection to my server EVERY TIME, but regular Chrome succeeds once, then fails all subsequent attempts. Weird, right?

Comment: Please provide a reduced code sample. Also ensure you're using Chrome 13 (unless your WebSocket server supports the newer spec)

Comment: Try installing Chrome Canary (basically Chrome 15), it supports the latest WebSocket spec (version 8), get it here http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs It will install side-by-side with your existing Chrome 13 install. If this fixes your problem then the issue is probably something fishy with the earlier WebSocket implementation  in Chrome 13 (which will get fixed soon with Chrome 14).

Comment: What do you mean, "reconnect"? With websockets, you only need to connect once. Then you send (and receive) as many messages as you want, until you explicitly close the connection. If Incognito "reconnects" before closing an earlier connection, this might indicate something special about Incognito.

Answer (score 2):

Websockets make a usual HTTP query to initially connect to server.
HTTP query also has cookies in the request.
In my case, the cookies were huge, and incognito mode doesn't have it, only session_id, so cleaning the cookies in regular Chrome did the deal.

Comment: It's workaround and not a solution. You can't ask users to keep cleaning cookies all the time.

Comment: It's not a workaround. I'm pinpointing the problem - server could reject the websocket connection because the HTTP request is broken. The difference between normal connection and incognito one is primarily in cookies. The server could reject connection because cookies are too big (my case) or somewhat broken otherwise. Please look into this part while debugging the problem.

If the server rejects websocket connection because of cookies, it would reject any other HTTP request with those cookies too, so you must fix the issue in the first place, like by limiting the accumulation of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has all to do with the latest hybi 10 draft spec.
Since Chrome 14, only this spec is supported.
The older specs aren't anymore.

Comment: Does incognito use another spec version?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. This may actually deal with the framework you used on the server side. My only suggestion not knowing your framework. Make sure that on the server you are using is correctly managing which socket you are receiving and sending data. IE the same socket.